# Force JSON-B to write Numbers as Strings when generating JSON

Tags: jax-rs, resteasy, jsonb-api, yasson

I'm dealing with large numbers in my Java code and because of the limitations of JavaScript (namely the 32-bit support of Integers), I need to write those numbers as Strings in the JSON returned by my application.

Is there a global configuration or annotation that will allow me to do this? I'd like to avoid writing custom serializers/adapters if possible.

I am using RestEasy with the new JSON-B/Yasson support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is using an adapter like this:

```
import javax.json.bind.adapter.JsonbAdapter;

public class AdapterIntegerToString implements JsonbAdapter<Integer, String> {

    @Override
    public String adaptToJson(Integer obj) throws Exception {
        return String.valueOf(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public Integer adaptFromJson(String obj) throws Exception {
        return Integer.parseInt(obj);
    }
}
```

And then annotated your property with:

```
@JsonbTypeAdapter(AdapterIntegerToString.class)
private Integer age;
```

Any other `Integer` no annotated will be treated as it is by default.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be the only solution at the moment, I gave up on using Yasson and went back to Jackson.